# Best way to dissolve and consume cysteine HCl monohydrate powder

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry

Does cysteine break down in filtered water?  Should this made more acidic?

If I mix cysteine powder in juice (something acidic maybe), does it remain at cysteine?  It seems that it can oxidize into cystine and lose some of its qualities.

Comment: I see an article titled `Cysteine stability in aqueous amino acid solutions`.  Looks like that might do the trick.  It goes on to say `Optimal conditions for cysteine stabilization in aqueous solutions of amino acids, available for parenteral protein feeding, were found`.  It is in Rushan; maybe I can use a translator.  I'm having trouble finding where to download the article.  I see only the abstract.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6431404

Comment: did you get the article? I am looking for it but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry at all about the oxidative dimerization of cysteine to cystine when you consume freshly prepared solutions.

In the lab, you'd use oxidants, such as $\ce{FeCl3}$ (in the presence of air) or hydrogen peroxide to achieve this reaction; both of which you're not likely to add to your amino acid diet!

As far as the article which you mentioned is concerned: The stabilization methods in question will only be relevant to maintain the composition of prefabricated and sterile-packed solutions over a long period of time.